# How to plot a parametric surface (helicoid) with LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I need to plot a helicoid in my document. I didn't find anything on the internet that would answer my question. Basically, I need to plot the surface designated by the equations

```
x = u * cos (v); 
y = u * sin (v);  
z = v.
```

Since these equations depend on u and v, I was unable to plot the surface. Plotting a helix is much simpler, because it only depends on one coordinate: x. For example, (Overleaf example):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{comment}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm, compat=1.9}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    [
    view={60}{30},
    ]
\addplot3[
    domain=0:5*pi,
    samples = 60,
    samples y=0,
]
({sin(deg(x))},
{cos(deg(x))},
{x});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

How to do this for helicoid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome! You only need to add one dimension to your plot.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{comment}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm, compat=1.16}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    [
    view={60}{30},
    ]
\addplot3[surf,shader=interp,
    domain=0:5*pi,
    samples=101,
    samples y=2,
]
({y*sin(deg(x))},
{y*cos(deg(x))},
{x});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or with a mesh. (The increase of `samples y` makes the mesh more meshy but also adds to the compilation time, the more so since we need to a add `z buffer=sort` or something along these lines.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{comment}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm, compat=1.16}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    [
    view={60}{30},
    ]
\addplot3[surf,
    domain=0:5*pi,
    samples=101,
    samples y=11,z buffer=sort
]
({y*sin(deg(x))},
{y*cos(deg(x))},
{x});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem!

Comment: By the way, do you know how to add a mesh to the surface?

Comment: @user4817 Sure, just drop `shader=interp`. In this plot the y samples are only two, so the mesh doesn't look impressive, but one also only needs two y samples. If you use `\addplot3[surf,
    domain=0:5*pi,
    samples=101,
    samples y=11,z buffer=sort
]
({y*sin(deg(x))},
{y*cos(deg(x))},
{x});` you get a more meshy mesh at the expense of a larger compilation time.

Comment: Thank you one more time!